# Syntax to inport xml data into sql database - line by line

Tags: java, mysql, xml, database, oracle

Thi is the first time I've used StackOverFlow. I'm hoping someone can help me. I have some database coursework and it's all a mystery to me.

I have to create a 2 attribute table:

ASS_FILM ( Fnum, Film),

where  the primary key, Fnum is an SQL 1992 datatype but film is of Oracle XMLType. Then I need to populate it with the contents of 5 xml files I have sitting on my desktop which include actors, directors genres etc line by line and then run queries like 'Display the names of all films which Tom Cruise acted in'.

I seem to have sussed creating the table. However, I can't seem to figure out the syntax for importing each xml file into each line of the table. I don't know if I've created the table wrong, or I'm importing the xml data wrong.

Any advice?

JAVA CODE:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE ASS2_FILM");

        //CREATE THE SQL TABLE/
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE ASS2_FILM(Enum VARCHAR(3)PK PRIMARY KEY, " + "film1 SYS.XMLTYPE)" + "");


        try{
        FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream ("C:\\Users\\Brendan\\Desktop\\Assignment\\film1.xml");
        XMLType xmlv = new XMLType (conn, fis1);
        System.out.println(xmlv.getStringVal());
        stmt.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO ASS2_FILM VALUES('Godfather,The', sys.XMLType.createXML(xmlv.getStringVal())+ DATE'2015-03-12')");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
            System.out.println("Error: Could not find film1.xml file.");
        }
```

XML CODE from the first XML file

```
<film>
<title>Godfather, The</title>
<year>1972</year>
<directors>
<director> Francis Ford Coppola</director>
</directors>
<genres>
<genre> Crime </genre>
<genre> Drame</genre>
<genre> Mafia </genre>
<genre>Adventure</genre>
</genres>
<plot> Son of a mafia boss takes over when his father is critically wounded </plot>
<cast>
<performer>
<actor>Marlon Brando</actor>
<role>Don Vito Corrleone</role>
</performer>
<performer>
<actor>Al Pacino</actor>
<role>Michael Corleone</role>
</performer>
<performer>
<actor>Diane Keaton</actor>
<role>Kay Adams Corleone</role>
</performer>
<performer>
<actor>Robert Duvall</actor>
<role>Tom Hagen</role>
</performer>
<performer>
<actor>James Caan</actor>
<role>Sonny Corleone</role>
</performer>
</cast>
</film>
```

Comment: table has quite a name lol!

Answer (score 0):

So here is my take on how you should proceed. Two approaches:

1. `ORM (Object relational Mapping)` is essentially you are looking for. It helps `java objects`(which have the structure of the `database schema`) to interact with the `database`. `Hibernate` is what you are looking for. But considering this is just an assignment. I would say do not go for it.
2. `JAXB framework` is very powerful when you think of converting `xml's into java objects`. And then you can iterate through `objects` and push the essentials in the `database` using the traditional `java-database connectivity`. You could go for this.

Hope this helps.